# Add a gallery for every user in a block

Tags: nodes, media

I want to be able to add a gallery for each user.
I understand how to create a content type. I considered building an image content type. I then thought I could add a view which would only display each user.

Is this best practice for creating a gallery for each user?

I am using Drupal 7, if this makes any difference.

I can get it working in a view but it doesn't seem to work in a block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are on a right path. The Views module, and content types can be used to build a simple gallery for a user.

1. Create a content type called Image Gallery.
2. Add a image field to above content type.
3. Create a view called user gallery.
4. Filter by Content Type Image Gallery.
5. Filter by Node author: Logged in user, if you want to show logged in users Gallery.
6. Add the contextual filter Author UID, if you want to dynamically pass the user ID from the URL and filter the Gallery Images.
7. For above your view page path should be user-gallery/% where % will be user id.

Answer (score 0):

The answer shows how you can control the output of a block so for example each user gets a different gallery. I found out this method for drupal 6 views 2. 
http://drupalsn.com/learn-drupal/drupal-questions/question-2650

**Drupal 6**

Here’s how i’d do it:
1) In the view admin page under arguments click on the User:name argument and scroll down the page where you’ll see some options for that argument under “Block: Configure Argument User: Name”.

2) Under “Action to take if argument is not present” select “Provide default argument” then under “Default argument type” select “PHP code” now we can enter some custom PHP code to get the username from the page URL assuming your username is the second argument in the URL
ie. publications/USERNAME

3) Now in the “PHP argument code” box enter the following PHP:

Again I’m assuming the URL is publications/USERNAME and what we are saying here is if the first URL argument is “publications” and the second URL argument is not blank then use the second argument as the views username argument.
4) You should select “hide view / page not found” in the “Action to take if argument does not validate” under “Validator options” that way views will check the user exists and find the view/block is they don’t have any content.

5) Lastly save the view and assign your block to the publications/USERNAME page.

That should do it, let me know if it works, i loaded up views and tested it so should be fine.