# Adjust a view so there is one image of size normal and other images are thumbnails

Tags: views, media

I have created a [gallery for every user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42350/add-a-gallery-for-every-user). I would now like to alter the view so that one of the images is a medium size and the other images are thumb nail size. I know you can adjust the layout in a view but I am not sure how to change the size of one image and keep the others as the default thumbnail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [View Nodes Split](http://drupal.org/project/views_nodes_split) module.

> This module allows site administrators or builders to have a different view mode for the first nodes of a view result.
>
> If you ever had (or currently have) this scenario: you have a view of nodes but you want that the first node (or first X nodes) to have a different view mode, then this module is for you. The module can split the results from a view into 2 lists. It actually does not make 2 separate lists, it just uses a a different view mode to render the first X nodes from a view.

You can also use a view attachment to display a node and attach more nodes to it. Make sure you offset your attached view by 1.