# How to add an image gallery to content type

Tags: nodes, media

What I need is to let the user add a few images in the content type, and after the user posts Title, Body message, these images should show as a gallery on the node.

I know how to do the gallery via views Gallerific, but how do you add this gallery to a node?

Answer (score 0):

This might be of interest to you. It uses a content type and views for each user.
[Add a gallery for every user in a block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42350/add-a-gallery-for-every-user-in-a-block) If you require further assistance please let me know. The answer is quite detailed and is broken up step by step. What version of Drupal are you using.